# Disconnecting Facebook from app on iOS6?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the latest Facebook iOS SDK, 3.1.1. I want to give users the option to "disconnect" our app from Facebook. I'm calling:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

That seems to work fine, but the next time I call

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:handler];
```

it immediately gives me a token, without asking the user to login again. I would expect it to ask the user again to authenticate. If there's no Facebook account set up on the device, it works fine, because it opens the web browser where it tells the user they've already authenticated the app and shows the 'Okay' button. But if it is set up, it just silently gets the token again and so the user's "disconnecting" the app has no effect.

Is anyone else having this issue, and how are you handling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't ask again because the iOS SDK has given the Facebook SDK a valid access token. This is just how Apple designed their Facebook (and Twitter) frameworks. There's nothing you can do about it. Personally I think it's great. The user should only have to tell their phone once that they accept an app.

Also note that the cached token may have expired. The Facebook SDK at present doesn't fully handle the case where the iOS SDK gives it an expired token.

If you want to test then you can delete the Facebook account on your device and re-add it. That should clear the cached token.

Comment: Thanks, it goes contrary to the way we set things up in our app but I guess it does make sense.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you care about having it always ask? Why does it matter?

Comment: Sorry mattjgalloway, I didn't see your comment. The reason is that users may be hesitant to grant the permission to the app when they just start using it. Perhaps they try things out, trigger the Facebook action, but then deny access. Later as they use the app more and start trusting it, perhaps they'd allow it access to their Facebook account, but it will never ask again.

Comment: That's OK :-). Hmm, I thought you were asking about the scenario where they accept, then disconnect in your app and then reconnect again and in that case it won't display the prompt to allow. The other problem in your comment I don't think should be the case. I thought that if you select "Don't Allow" and then re-ask for permission, the prompt does come up again.

Comment: If they 'disconnect' in your app, iOS will still remember they allowed it, so when the app asks for permission next time, it will immediately get it (no prompt displayed). But if the user denied permission to the app, the system will automatically reject any subsequent requests for permissions (perhaps it times out after a while, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
- (void)openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehavior)behavior completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

with *FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView* as the behaviour solved my problem. It opens the login modal box and forgets the user cookies.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that means you need to completely skip the built-in Facebook account, which I'd like to avoid. In the meantime, we just decided to leave out the 'log out' button. If you want, you can always do it from system settings.